# Move vector between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, move-semantics

I have a thread that continuously collects data items with a public interface like this:

```
class MyThread {
public:
    class Item {
        // ...
    };

    startup();
    shutdown();

    bool hasItems() const;

    // retrieve collected items
    std::vector<Item>&& items();
private:
    std::mutex itemMutex;
    std::vector<Item> currentItems;
};
```

Retrieving the items should also clear the thread's item list. I return an rvalue so that the move constructor is invoked on the calling side. Of course, retrieving the items should be thread-safe, so the implementation looks like this:

```
std::vector<MyThread::Item>&& MyThread::items() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(itemMutex);
    return std::move(currentItems);
}
```

I think that the lock is released too early here: the function returns the rvalue'd vector, but a move constructor hasn't necessarily be called with it when the `std::lock_guard` is destroyed and releases the mutex. So from my understanding, this isn't thread-safe. Am I right? How can I make it thread-safe?

Comment: If you change your function to return a `std::vector<MyThread::Item>` rather than an rvalue reference then there is no problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right, it isn't threadsafe as the move will happen after the method returns, at which point the lock will have been released. To fix it just move the vector into a local variable and return that :

```
std::vector<MyThread::Item> MyThread::items() 
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(itemMutex);
    return std::vector<MyThread::Item>(std::move(currentItems));
}
```

Comment: Is the returned value still an rvalue that will be moved when I call `std::vector<MyThread::Item> list (myThreadInstance.items());`? To me, it looks like this would invoke a deep copy.

Comment: When you assign it to a local (`std::vector<MyThread::Item> items=items()`) it will be an rvalue.

Comment: I do believe, you don't need to explicitly use the std::move(). If there is a move-ctor, it will be used anyway when returning the value (_currentItems_), so simply:  `return currentItems;` should suffice.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper `return currentItems;` only works if `currentItems` is a function-local variable. Here it is a data member so the `std::move` is required.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that currentItem is in "partially formed" state after it's moved from (see [What lasts after using std::move c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850196/what-lasts-after-using-stdmove-c11)). 
In one of the answers there there's an example how to remedy that problem:

```
std::vector<MyThread::Item> MyThread::items() 
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(itemMutex);
    auto tmp =  std::move(currentItems);
    currentItems.clear();
    return tmp;
}
```

I would rather go for the most straightforward solution and let the compiler do the heavy work:

```
std::vector<MyThread::Item> MyThread::items() 
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(itemMutex);
    std::vector<MyThread::Item> tmp;
    tmp.swap(currentItems);
    return tmp;
}
```