# Can you reuse a moved std::string?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Given this example:

```
 std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::string curr;
    for (auto c : str) {
        if (c == DELIMITER) {
            result.push_back(std::move(curr)); // ATTENTION HERE!
        } else {
            curr.push_back(c);
        }
    }
    result.push_back(std::move(curr));
    return result;
}
```

Can I reuse the `curr` std:string? This snippet seems working: after `curr` is moved inside
the `result` vector, it becomes empty. I want to be sure this is not an undefined behavior in the standard and it isn't working only because of luck.

Comment: It's left in a valid but unspecified state. Not guaranteed to be empty.

Comment: i think the difference here is subtle, e.g: small string optimization

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a few exceptions (smart pointers, for instance), moved-from objects are left in a valid but unspecified state.

In a `std::string` that uses the small string optimization, for instance, if the string is small, there is no dynamic allocation, and a move is a copy. In that case it is perfectly valid for the implementation to leave the source string untouched, and not incur the extra cost of emptying the string.

Answer (score 4):

May be, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168917) will be useful

In short, for reuse you need to call `.clear` method

Comment: You don't _need_ to call `clear()`. You can just assign to it, or resize it, or any other operation with no preconditions.

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

...all standard library functions that accept rvalue reference parameters (such as std::vector::push_back) are guaranteed to leave the moved-from argument in valid but unspecified state.

Comment: Didn't answer the question of the op about whether it can be reused or not.