# std::vector::emplace_back and std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move-semantics

Is there any advantage of using `std::vector::emplace_back` and `std::move` together? or it is just redundant since `std::vector::emplace_back` will do an inplace-construction?

Cases for clarification:

```
std::vector<std::string> bar;
```

**First:**

```
bar.emplace_back(std::move(std::string("some_string")));
```

**Second:**

```
std::string str("some_string");
bar.emplace_back(std::move(str));
```

**Third:**

```
bar.emplace_back(std::move("some_string"));
```

Comment: The third move, at least, is pointless. That literal string there is const, so it cannot be moved.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the second version, there is an advantage. Calling `emplace_back` will call the move constructor of `std::string` when `std::move` is used, which could save on a copy (so long as that string isn't stored in a SSO buffer). Note that this is essentially the same as `push_back` in this case.

`std::move` in the first version is unnecessary, as the string is already a prvalue.

`std::move` in the third version is irrelevant, as a string literal cannot be moved from.

The simplest and most efficient method is this:

```
bar.emplace_back("some_string");
```

That requires no unnecessary `std::string` constructions as the literal is perfect-forwarded to the constructor.

Comment: Could you please clarify "same as `push_back` in this case"? In which case exactly? Can `emplace_back` always be replaced with `push_back` if its argument is `move`d?

Comment: in the first and second case, `emplace_back` could be replaced with `push_back`

Comment: If `emplace_back` was replaced with `push_back`, would that not result in a copy rather than a move?

Comment: @HugoBurd late reply but no, `push_back` has a moving version

Answer (score 9):

`emplace_back` calls to somehthing like

```
new (data+size) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

if `args` are basic - non - rvalue-referenced `std::string`, the expression will compile to

```
new (data+size) std::string(str); //str is lvalue - calls std::string::string(const string& rhs)
```

meaning the copy constructor will take place.
but, if you use `std::move` on `str`, the code will compile to

```
new (data+size) std::string(str); //str is r-value reference, calls std::string::string(string&& rhs)
```

so move semantics takes place. this is a huge performance gain.
do note, that `str` is lvalue, it has a name, so in order to create r-value-reference from it, you must use `std::move`.

in the example

```
vec.emplace_back("some literal");
```

the code will compile to

```
new (data+size) std::string("literal"); //calls std::string::string(const char*);
```

so no temporaries.

the third example is nonsense. you cannot move literals.

Answer (score 6):

The whole idea of `emplace_back` is to get rid of copying and moving operations. You just need to pass input parameters of `std::string` into `emplace_back`. A `std::string` object will be constructed inside `emplace_back` method.

```
bar.emplace_back("some_string");
```

If you already have a string, it makes sense to use `std::move`. A `std::string` object will be constructed inside `emplace_back` by moving data from `str`.

```
std::string str("some_string");
bar.emplace_back(std::move(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a point of doing so in the second case. Consider this code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> bar;
    std::string str("some_string");
    bar.emplace_back(std::move(str)); str.clear();
    // bar.emplace_back(str);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

If you change the comment to the line above, you can see that you will end up with two copies of "some_string" (one in `bar` and one in `str`). So it does change something.

Otherwise, the first one is moving a temporary, and the third is moving a constant string literal. It does nothing.

Comment: With your code (without the commented one) dont you move away the str resulting str is dangling then passing it to cout? This seems dangerous for me..

Comment: @Wolfgang Thanks, excellent point. `str.clear()` should [first be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168823/reusing-a-moved-container/9168917#9168917). Updated the answer.