# Using std::move with vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have a question about using `std::move` in C++.

Let's say I have the following class, which in its constructor takes a `std::vector` as a parameter:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::vector<char> v): v(v) {}
private:
    std::vector<char> v;
};
```

But if I write the following somewhere:

```
std::vector<char> v;
A a(v);
```

the copy constructor of `std::vector` will be called twice, right?
So should I write constructor for `A` like the following?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::vector<char> v): v(std::move(v)) {}
private:
    std::vector<char> v;
};
```

And what if I would like to call the following?

```
std::vector<char> v;
A a(std::move(v));
```

Is that okay with the second version of the constructor, or should I create another constructor for `A` that takes `std::vector<char>&&`?

Comment: Why would there be 2 copies to the copy constructor?

Comment: @MinhTran copy ctor would be first called to to create the temporary `v` variable (the parameter in A ctor) and the second time to create the v member variable from v temporary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second scheme is fine.

The vector will just be moved twice with the second version (which moves the by-value parameter into your member). If you don't mind the cost of the extra move, you can stick with just moving the by-value parameter into your member.

If you do mind, then make two constructors for different value categories of the parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Make two constructors:
The first constructor should be by const&, the second as rvalue&& so it can use move semantics:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const std::vector<char>& v_) : v(v_) { std::cout << "const& ctor\n"; }
    A(std::vector<char>&& v_) : v(std::move(v_)) { std::cout << "rvalue&& ctor\n"; }
private:
    std::vector<char> v;
};
```

Test:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<char> v1{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
    A a1(v1);
    A a2(std::vector<char>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

> const& ctor
>
> rvalue&& ctor

Answer (score 3):

Many times with vectors you would be fine by accepting `vector` by value and moving from it. So,

```
A(std::vector<char> v): v(std::move(v)) {}
```

However, this assumes that you are only calling it for 'natural' lvalues or temporaries. Meaning, it would be performant for cases like

```
A a(std::vector<char>{....}); // <--- 1
std::vector<char> my_vec;
A b(my_vec); // <--- 2
```

If you expect to call it with an lvalue which you'd like to be moved from, like in your example, than you need two constructors - with  `const lvalue` reference and `rvalue` references:

```
A(const std::vector<char>& v) : v(v) { }
A(std::vector<char>&& v) : v(std::move(v)) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write a move constructor!

```
A::A( std::vector<char>&& vec): v(std::move(vec) {}
```

If you did not write that, you get one more copy here.

You have to keep in mind that your vector will be moved "away". So if you write something like:

```
std::vector<char> v;
A a(std::move(v));
```

so your vector v should not used after the call of constructor of A. All elements are moved away and iterators to the content are invalid. The vector can be used to store new data.

So if you write

```
std::vector<char> v;
A a(v);
```

and this will result in a move like in your example, nobody would expect the move.

Comment: Actually, I read that vector can be used after moving: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168823/reusing-a-moved-container

Comment: There is no "away" happening. The vector is just empty after the move. You can use it to store new values. Only existing iterators should not be used.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I clarify this in my answer