# Reuse variable after move

Tags: c++, move-semantics, stdmove

Is it okay to do the following? The following code is using the vector v again in the loop (next iteration) after moving it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void test(vector<int>&& v) {
    cout << v.size() << endl;
    v.push_back(5);
}

void test2(vector<int>& v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        test(move(v));
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    test2(v);    
}
```

Comment: `std::move` does not move anything, it's just a type conversion. It's probably the most misleading name in the entire standard.

Comment: @molbdnilo ...but is neat. `std::as_rvalue` has five extra keystrokes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reusing a moved container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168823/reusing-a-moved-container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, but the intention that you are communicating is wrong.

If someone sees the declaration of function `test` he will think that when calling the function he is giving away the ownership of the variable that he is passing, because the variable will be moved.

In general, after a call to `std::move(v)` you should not reuse `v`.

What you should do in this case is declare `test` as `void test(std::vector<int>& v)` and you should call it just with `test(v)`.
In this way it is clear that `test` will modify `v`, but you will be able to use it later.

Comment: In general, after a call to `std::move(v)`, `v` is in a valid but indeterminate state. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168917/21475

Answer (score 2):

`std::move` just converts argument passed to rvalue, but doesn't perform move operation itself.

Given `test(move(v));`, `std::move` converts `v` to `rvalue`, which gets bound to reference parameter `v` (so it refers to the parameter `v` of `test2`, i.e. the object `v` defined in `main`). No new `vector` object is constructed, and no move constructor or move assignment operator is called.

Comment: Yes, no move because `test()` doesn't construct another object (however I had to test it with an [example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ch9qP4rzs) because I'm always wary about these things)